# Is there a way to limit number of packet captures with tcpflow?

Tags: networking, sniffing, tcpdump

I want to limit the number of captured packets, such as:

`tcpdump -c 20`

I want to use `tcpflow` instead. Is this possible? The console throws a syntax error using `tcpflow` with the `-c` parameter.

edit - Even if there was a way to limit the flow to only read one packet, or copy only 1 packet to the text file, rather then endlessly run.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `tcpflow` manpage. `tpcflow` isn't actually capturing packets, but an entire "flow" of data. The manpage shows you can add the `-b` parameter to capture a maximum amount of bytes.

Capturing a certain amount of packets will be much harder, since you then manually need to divide the whole data you capture this way.